# Mysql between dates and InnoDB

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have the query:

```
SELECT * FROM MY TABLE WHERE END_TIME BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

when **END_TIME** is :

```
`END_TIME` datetime default NULL,
```

This query stop working properly when i move my table work with:

```
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

is moving from MyISAM to InnoDB cause the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "stopped working properly?"

Comment: the query stop returning results in the selected between datetime

Comment: the query runs every 30 sec and the between parameters is current_time and current_time-30sec: no results are selected now

Answer (score 0):

Well, you changed the database engine, now the null is handled in a different way.

```
SELECT * FROM MY TABLE WHERE END_TIME BETWEEN '2013-01-01 AND ?
```

valid query

```
SELECT * FROM MY TABLE WHERE END_TIME BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND null
```

will always return 0 rowns

rewrite your query to

```
SELECT * FROM MY TABLE WHERE END_TIME BETWEEN ? AND now()
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM MY TABLE WHERE END_TIME >=0
```